# method parameter vs. getter in subclass

Tags: java

We had a discussion in the office, but neither side was convinced. Lets say we have

```
enum Food {
    CHICKEN, HAMBURGER, FISH;
}
```

We need multiple implementations of Dog, which need to answer, whether they are happy, which depends on whether they like food given to them and maybe some other stuff. It needs to be very flexible. Which is better:
**A:**

```
abstract class Dog {
    //not sure if this can be abstract in reality, but does it matter?
    abstract Set<Food> getFavoriteFoods();

    boolean isFoodOk(){
        return getFavoriteFoods().contains(Food.CHICKEN);
    }

    //in reality sometimes more conditions are needed here...
    boolean isHappy(){
        return isFoodOk();
    }
}



public class BullDog extends Dog {
    static final Set<Food> FAVORITE_FOODS = new HashSet<Food>();
    static {
        FAVORITE_FOODS.add(Food.CHICKEN);
        FAVORITE_FOODS.add(Food.FISH);
    }

    Set<Food> getFavoriteFoods(){
        return FAVORITE_FOODS;
    }
}
```

**OR B:**

```
abstract class Dog {
    abstract boolean isHappy();

    boolean isFoodOk(Set<Food> f){
        return f.contains(Food.CHICKEN);
    }
}

public class BullDog extends Dog {
    static final Set<Food> FAVORITE_FOODS = new HashSet<Food>();
    static {
        FAVORITE_FOODS.add(Food.CHICKEN);
        FAVORITE_FOODS.add(Food.FISH);
    }

    @Override
    boolean isHappy() {
        return isFoodOk(FAVORITE_FOODS);
    }
}
```

If the answer will be A I will have another question.

**NOTE:** I edited the code because there was a silly mistake there - of course FAVORITE_FOODS should be declared in BullDog, not Dog. But that does not answer the question.

Comment: Not very useful comment without explanation, but for me 'B' is much more clear.

Comment: Neither is good. Each animal should have its own `MoodResolver` implementation.

Comment: @siledh where would all the common code for all the Dog races would be? (in reality, there is quite a lot, I may have oversimplified)

Comment: After your edit, your design is still wrong. Note my answer to see a design that supports every dog having its own set of favorite food, but each race define which food its is favorite.

Comment: @SauliusŠimčikas might go into some abstract/base implementation of `MoodResolver` interface. But that actually gets us back to your original question...

Answer (score 2):

I would say none, since in all the approaches the `Set<Food>` is marked as `static final` thus the same set will be shared among all the instances of `Dog` class. Also, by declaring the `Set` as `static final` doesn't mean its contents cannot be modified, so in fact any client of `Dog` class or any subclass may add new Food or even clear it and all the `Dog`s will be affected.

This approach could do:

```
public abstract class Dog {
    //this field should be final only so the variable cannot be modified
    protected final Set<Food> favoriteFood;

    protected Dog(Food ... food) {
        //now the Set cannot be modified as well
        favoriteFood = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<Food>(Arrays.asList(food)));
    }

    //no need to be abstract, and clients cannot modify this set
    public Set<Food> getFavoriteFoods() {
        //I would recommend returning a new set that 
        return favoriteFood;
    }

    //You need to check if the dog likes the food to see if its ok
    public boolean isFoodOk(Food food){
        //not sure if your requirement is that it always should compare with CHICKEN, really odd...
        return getFavoriteFoods().contains(food); //Food.CHICKEN);
    }

    //IMO this method needs a complete redesign, since I don't know the details I can't provide a solution =\
    //at most it can be an abstract method and let each dog subclass implement it
    public abstract boolean isHappy();
    //boolean isHappy(){
    //    return isFoodOk();
    //}
}

public class BullDog extends Dog {
    public BullDog() {
        super(Food.CHICKEN, Food.FISH);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isHappy() {
        //define how the bulldog is happy
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: many good ideas but why the constructor? why not isFoodOk(Food ... favoriteFoods)? of course, it's not always chicken, there is a method getServedFood()

Comment: @SauliusŠimčikas I just made some changes based on your current design. If you want/need `isFoodOk` to receive multiple `Food`, then use `Food ... food` as parameter instead.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a very realistic model of the world: all dogs will be happy, no matter what food is available.

Seriously: neither A nor B are good, because the FAVORITE_FOOD is a class attribute of the abstract Dog class. It would make some sense to have it as class attribute per race. Or, more realistic, as instance attribute for each individual dog.

Comment: Sorry, that was a silly mistake I made only in this simplified example. I will edit the question. But in reality, all dogs of the same race have the same list FAVORITE_FOOD.

Comment: How many dogs do you know, @SauliusŠimčikas? It's simply not true. Just like it is silly to say that "all Germans love beer". I mean, it's not really silly, but simply false.

Answer (score 0):

What is specific for `Dog` types is favourite foods. So they need to answer the question 'what is your favourite food?' with the implementation of `getFavoriteFoods`. Being happy is not a question to ask to all `Dog` types differently. So A is better, in my opinion.